# What forces make objects fly away from the axis of rotation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, centrifugal-force

If two spheres are mounted on a smooth horizontal bar along which they can slide and were initially brought together and connected by a  thread. Then the whole assembly is set into rotation about a vertical axis. Then after a period of free rotation, the thread is burned up. Naturally, the spheres fly apart.

My question is, what forces make it move that way. Why don't the two spheres stay at the original radius from the vertical axis.

Image from irodov's fundamental laws of mechanics.

EDIT:[image]

Comment: 1) Yes, i think the bar still rotates afterwards. 2.I want to know about that too.

Comment: Ah ok I see by the picture that I had the wrong idea here. I will adjust my answer accordingly when I have time.

Comment: I actually decided just to delete my answer. I was assuming that we wanted to keep the same angular velocity of the bar, and this was not the case. The other answers here are sufficient to answer your question, so I figured my answer is no longer needed, and it would be pointless to just repeat what others have said. I would say @CortAmmon has the best answer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No force is required for an object to move radially outward. If no force is acting on them then they will move in a straight line at constant speed.

In radial coordinates any straight line necessarily has a changing radial coordinate. If you start out perpendicular to a radius then any straight line automatically has an increasing radius.

This is not due to forces, it is just geometry. Straight lines have increasing radius so an inertial object, which moves in a straight line, will therefore have an increasing radius.

Comment: That is incorrect. They do go outward at a constant velocity. The derivative of the radial coordinate is not constant, but the velocity is.

Comment: Agreed, but that doesn’t contradict my comments

Comment: That isn’t its velocity, that is it’s change in radial coordinate. For non-rectilinear coordinate systems they are not the same thing. The velocity is constant, the change in radial coordinate is not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83859/discussion-between-aaron-stevens-and-dale).

Answer (score 1):

They don't move radially outwards....they continue to move with the velocity at the instant the string was burnt. There is no external force(tension in string) to change the velocity after it's burnt

Comment: Yes, but eventually the radius of the orbit will increase while the angular velocity decreases right. Why do they behave that way.

Comment: It's been some time since I've thought of rotational mechanics..so correct me if Im wrong but I think they stop orbiting and angular veocity remains constant since angular momentum doesn't change...not sure though...wait for other answers or give it another thought

Comment: The balls will fly outwards. In the rotating frame there is a centrifugal force.

Answer (score 0):

The spheres will follow a path described by the equations of motion.  If they could escape the bar completely when the thread is burned, they will continue in a straight line at a constant speed.  Try it and you'll see.  The system you describe is a bit complicated, with normal forces and friction forces acting all over the place.  The usual variant of this is to have the two balls on the end of the bar, so that when you burn the thread they immediately leave the bar.  That one is easier to think through first, then approach the more complicated one using the same principles.  Accordingly, I'll use a lot of verbiage from the simple case, and you can add in all the physical forces associated with the precise geometry of your experiment.  The important effects, such as centrifugal acceleration, occur identically in both cases.

In an inertial frame (i.e. not rotating), the equations of motion are the simple ones we learn about.  F=ma, and objects move in a straight line unless a force acts on them.  These are the easy cases we learn about in physics class.  From these equations, we see that if there's no forces acting on the balls (which is true after the thread is burned and the spheres fly off the rod), they'll go in a straight line.

In a rotating frame, the rules are a bit different.  For this, we consider a frame which rotates with the bar.  This is the frame where your intuition is running into trouble trying to figure out why the balls don't stay stationary.

A leap of intuition: the motion of objects shouldn't depend on the frame we use.  An object on a Ferris wheel moves exactly the same regardless of whether we do math from the perspective of someone on the ground or someone on the Ferris wheel.  Thus whatever results we get from our on-the-ground thinking we should get the same motion in our on-the-bar thinking.

If you do the calculus, you find that the equations of motion for a rotating frame have two extra term that the inertial ones do not.  One of those is the centripetal term, $m \omega^2r$ outward, where $\omega$ is the angular rotation rate of the frame.  This term can be thought of as a "correction" term to yield the same physical results as if we did the calculations in an inertial frame.

So you have two ways to think of it.  One is you can think in a nice easy inertial frame.  In this frame, objects want to move in a straight line, so when the thread is burned through, they will move in a straight line at a constant velocity unless acted on by a force.  Or you can think about it in a rotating frame.  However, if you think about it in a rotating frame, you have to remember that there is a pseudoforce, the cetrifugal force effectively pulling all objects away from the center of rotation.

Note that all of this is completely independent of the objects that are moving.  If you watch a soccer ball roll across the field, you can model it's motion using F=ma.  You can also spin around in circles on the sidelines, and calculate its path in the rotating frame, accounting for the centrifugal psudoforce.  You will get the same results.  The ball will reach the goal at exactly the same time, whether you were spinning while you watched it or not!

Comment: @AaronStevens I tried hard to point out that they would move in a straight line *if there is no force applied to it*.  If there is a force applied to it (such as the force of the bar), then its path will be different.  However, its hard to tell what the precise forces will look like while the balls are traveling away from eachother without additional clarification.  The usual variant of this experiment, where the balls are free from forces after the string is burned, is much easier to push through.

Comment: @AaronStevens In either case, the argument is still that you can choose to view the problem in an inertial frame, or a rotating frame.  Both yield the same answer, they just come to it in different ways.

Comment: hello all.  Thanks a lot for the answers. For clarification, here are some edits. Let Friction forces be very small and assume that all the mass of the whole assembly is concentrated in the spheres.